# How to save a fcolumn with "/" using CakePHP Table save method?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

Here is my code:

```
$conn = \Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::get('default');
$conn->logQueries(true);
$entities[] = $this->patchEntity($entity, $insertData);
$this->saveMany($entities);
```

And its generating the following insert header:

INSERT INTO aneel_sdi_razao_sintetico (Ide_RO_Sintetico, Cd_ODI, Cd_SubODI, Txt_Desc_ODI, Nr_TI, Txt_Tipo_Obra, Txt_Class_Obra, Vl_UC/UAR, Vl_COM, Vl_Proj_ST, Vl_Mont_ST, Vl_Frete_ST, Vl_Fis_ST, Vl_Sup_ST, Vl_Ger_ST, Vl_Proj_MOP, Vl_Mont_MOP, Vl_Frete_MOP, Vl_Fis_MOP, Vl_Sup_MOP, Vl_Ger_MOP, Vl_Tot_CA, Vl_JOA, Vl_Outros, Vl_Tot_Proj, Dt_Ini_Proj, Dt_Energ, Dt_Uniti, Pct_OE, txt_PLPT_OE, txt_Doa_OE, txt_Incor_OE, Nr_Fases, SDI_importacoes_id) VALUES ...

And the following error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/UAR, Vl_COM, Vl_Proj_ST, Vl_Mont_ST, Vl_Frete_ST, Vl_Fis_ST, Vl_Sup_ST, Vl_Ger_' at line 1

The problem is the field "Vl_UC/UAR" must have this "/" and i don't know how to place the "`" character to make the MySQL accept it.

Someone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If a column contains a `/` it needs to be quoted and the backtick is an subshell in PHP so:

```
\`Vl_UC/UAR\`
```

However its probably easier to rename the column.

Comment: Yes, but how can i do it using the cake save method?